# Kotlin: function input parameter of certain class is loosing value after other class is being mapped with ModelMapper

Tags: android, kotlin, modelmapper

I have a method where I'm mapping an AWThoughtDTO to AWThought using ModelMapper library, and with an unknown -for me- reason the input variable awPainting is loosing its value just after map line is executed.

I cannot understand why this happens as AWThoughtDTO is being mapped to AWThought, and AWPainting has nothing to do in this process :s

AWPainting has a value of "background00105" ... whatever, and after map line is executing the value is being changed to "background00000".

```
fun getRandomThought(
    context: Context?,
    idLanguage: Int,
    awPainting: AWPainting,
    trackId: Int
): AWThought {
    val mapAlreadyReadThoughts = mapAll(alreadyReadThoughts, AWThoughtDTO::class.java)
    val thought = thoughtService.getRandomThought(idLanguage, mapAlreadyReadThoughts)
    val mapThought = thought.map(AWThought::class.java)
    mapThought.painting = awPainting
    mapThought.trackId = trackId
    setThoughtTrackIds(mapThought, trackId)
    alreadyReadThoughts.add(mapThought)
    saveAlreadyReadThoughtsList(alreadyReadThoughts, context)
    return mapThought
}
```

Map:

```
fun <D> AWThoughtDTO.map(outClass: Class<D>): D {
    return modelMapper!!.map(this, outClass)
}
```

AWPainting:

```
object AWPainting: Serializable {

    var id: Int = 0
    var author: String = ""
    var authorEmail: String = ""
    var url: String = ""
    var filename: String = ""
    var active: Int = 0
    var thoughtId: Int = 0

    private lateinit var context: Context
    private lateinit var paintingService: PaintingService
    private lateinit var awPreferences: AWPreferences

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "background" + String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%04d", id)
    }

    fun init(
        context: Context,
        paintingService: PaintingService,
        awPreferences: AWPreferences
    ) {
        this.context = context
        this.paintingService = paintingService
        this.awPreferences = awPreferences
    }

    val randomPainting: AWPainting
        get() {
            val paintingsDTO = paintingService.getPaintings()
            var paintings = mapAll(paintingsDTO, AWPainting::class.java).toMutableList()
            paintings.removeAll(alreadySeenPaintings)
            if (paintings.isEmpty()) {
                val asp = ArrayList<AWPainting>()
                saveAlreadySeenPaintingsList(asp, context)
                paintings = mapAll(paintingService.getPaintings(), AWPainting::class.java)
            }
            val painting = paintings.getRandom(paintings.size)
            alreadySeenPaintings.add(painting)
            saveAlreadySeenPaintingsList(alreadySeenPaintings, context)
            return painting
        }

    private val alreadySeenPaintings: MutableList<AWPainting>
        get() {
            val aspDTO = awPreferences.alreadySeenPaintingsFromPreferences
            var asp: MutableList<AWPainting>? = mapAllNull(aspDTO, AWPainting::class.java)
            if (asp == null) asp = ArrayList()
            return asp
        }

    private fun saveAlreadySeenPaintingsList(asp: MutableList<AWPainting>, context: Context?) {
        val aspPref = Enum.Preference.ALREADYSEENPAINTINGS
        awPreferences.saveArrayListInPreferences(asp, aspPref, context)
    }
}
```

AWThought:

```
object AWThought: Serializable {

    var id: Int = 0
    var thought: String = ""
    var author: String = ""
    var authorEmail: String = ""
    var idLanguage: Int = 0
    var active: Int = 0

    var painting: AWPainting = AWPainting
    var trackId = 0
    var spotifyPreviewUrl: String = ""
    var trackIdI = 0
    var trackIdV = 0
    var trackIdIV = 0
    var calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    private lateinit var awDate: AWDate
    private lateinit var thoughtService: ThoughtService
    private lateinit var awPreferences: AWPreferences
    private lateinit var awCryptography: Cryptography

    fun init(
        thoughtService: ThoughtService,
        awDate: AWDate,
        awPreferences: AWPreferences,
        awCryptography: Cryptography
    ) {
        this.thoughtService = thoughtService
        this.awPreferences = awPreferences
        this.awDate = awDate
        this.awCryptography = awCryptography
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return thought
    }

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (other !is AWThought) {
            return false
        }
        return other.id == id
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = id
        result = 31 * result + thought.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + author.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + authorEmail.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + idLanguage
        result = 31 * result + active
        result = 31 * result + painting.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + trackId
        result = 31 * result + spotifyPreviewUrl.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + trackIdI
        result = 31 * result + trackIdV
        result = 31 * result + trackIdIV
        result = 31 * result + calendar.hashCode()
        return result
    }

    val alreadyReadThoughts: MutableList<AWThought>
        get() {
            val art = awPreferences.alreadyReadThoughtsFromPreferences
            var alreadyReadThoughts = mapAllNull(art, AWThought::class.java)
            if (alreadyReadThoughts == null) alreadyReadThoughts = ArrayList()
            return alreadyReadThoughts
        }

    fun getRandomThought(
        context: Context?,
        idLanguage: Int,
        awPainting: AWPainting,
        trackId: Int
    ): AWThought {
        val mapAlreadyReadThoughts = mapAll(alreadyReadThoughts, AWThoughtDTO::class.java)
        val thought = thoughtService.getRandomThought(idLanguage, mapAlreadyReadThoughts)
        val abc = awPainting.clone()
        val mapThought = thought.map(AWThought::class.java) // map(thought, AWThought::class.java)
        mapThought.painting = awPainting
        mapThought.trackId = trackId
        setThoughtTrackIds(mapThought, trackId)
        alreadyReadThoughts.add(mapThought)
        saveAlreadyReadThoughtsList(alreadyReadThoughts, context)
        return mapThought
    }

    private fun setThoughtTrackIds(thought: AWThought, trackId: Int) {
        when (awPreferences.musicType) {
            Enum.MusicType.INSTRUMENTAL -> updateThoughtInstrumentalTrackId(thought, trackId)
            Enum.MusicType.VOICE -> updateThoughtVoiceTrackId(thought, trackId)
            else -> updateThoughtInstrumentalVoiceTrackId(thought, trackId)
        }
    }

    private fun updateThoughtInstrumentalTrackId(thought: AWThought, trackId: Int) {
        thought.trackIdI = trackId
        val trackIdV = AWTrack.getRandomTrackId(Enum.MusicType.VOICE)
        thought.trackIdV = trackIdV
        val trackIdIV = AWTrack.getRandomTrackId(Enum.MusicType.INSTRUMENTALVOICE)
        thought.trackIdIV = trackIdIV
    }

    private fun updateThoughtVoiceTrackId(thought: AWThought, trackId: Int) {
        val trackIdI = AWTrack.getRandomTrackId(Enum.MusicType.INSTRUMENTAL)
        thought.trackIdI = trackIdI
        thought.trackIdV = trackId
        val trackIdIV = AWTrack.getRandomTrackId(Enum.MusicType.INSTRUMENTALVOICE)
        thought.trackIdIV = trackIdIV
    }

    private fun updateThoughtInstrumentalVoiceTrackId(thought: AWThought, trackId: Int) {
        val trackIdI = AWTrack.getRandomTrackId(Enum.MusicType.INSTRUMENTAL)
        thought.trackIdI = trackIdI
        val trackIdV = AWTrack.getRandomTrackId(Enum.MusicType.VOICE)
        thought.trackIdV = trackIdV
        thought.trackIdIV = trackId
    }

    @JvmStatic
    fun updateAlreadyReadThoughtsList(context: Context?, thought: AWThought) {
        val art = alreadyReadThoughts
        for (awThought in art) {
            if (awThought.id == thought.id) {
                awThought.trackId = thought.trackId
                awThought.trackIdI = thought.trackIdI
                awThought.trackIdV = thought.trackIdV
                awThought.trackIdIV = thought.trackIdIV
            }
        }
        saveAlreadyReadThoughtsList(art, context)
    }

    private fun saveAlreadyReadThoughtsList(art: MutableList<AWThought>, context: Context?) {
        val artPref = Enum.Preference.ALREADYREADTHOUGHTS
        awPreferences.saveArrayListInPreferences(art, artPref, context)
    }

    fun saveThoughtInPreferences(context: Context, thought: AWThought, _lastRun: String?) {
        var lastRun = _lastRun
        val todayThoughtDate = Enum.Preference.TODAYTHOUGHTDATE
        val todayThoughtData = Enum.Preference.TODAYTHOUGHTDATA
        val reminderCal = Calendar.getInstance()
        val today = awDate.generateDate4Insert(reminderCal)
        val packageName = context.packageName
        val prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(packageName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val thoughtData = "ArtAndWords:${thought.id}@${thought.painting.id}@${thought.trackId}"
        val cipherThought = awCryptography.cipherText(thoughtData)
        lastRun = lastRun ?: prefs.getString(todayThoughtDate, "")
        if (lastRun == "" || lastRun != today) {
            prefs.edit().putString(todayThoughtDate, today).apply()
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit()
                .putString(todayThoughtDate, today).apply()
            //
            prefs.edit().putString(todayThoughtData, cipherThought).apply()
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit()
                .putString(todayThoughtData, cipherThought).apply()
        }
    }

    fun findThoughtByPaintingInAlreadyRead(
        alreadyReadThoughts: MutableList<AWThought>,
        painting: AWPainting
    ): AWThought? {
        for (thought in alreadyReadThoughts) {
            if (thought.id == painting.thoughtId) {
                return thought
            }
        }
        return null
    }

    fun findThoughtByIdInAlreadyRead(thoughtId: Int): AWThought? {
        val alreadyReadThoughts = alreadyReadThoughts
        for (thought in alreadyReadThoughts) {
            if (thought.id == thoughtId) {
                return thought
            }
        }
        return null
    }

    fun updateThoughtTrackIdByMusicType(currMusicType: Int, thought: AWThought, trackId: Int) {
        when (currMusicType) {
            Enum.MusicType.INSTRUMENTAL -> if (thought.trackIdI == 0) {
                thought.trackIdI = trackId
            }
            Enum.MusicType.VOICE -> if (thought.trackIdV == 0) {
                thought.trackIdV = trackId
            }
            else -> if (thought.trackIdIV == 0) {
                thought.trackIdIV = trackId
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure it'll end being something specific to my app/code.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did a slight modification, given the method:

```
fun getRandomThought(
        context: Context?,
        idLanguage: Int,
        awPainting: AWPainting,
        trackId: Int
    ): AWThought {
        val mapAlreadyReadThoughts = mapAll(alreadyReadThoughts, AWThoughtDTO::class.java)
        val thought = thoughtService.getRandomThought(idLanguage, mapAlreadyReadThoughts)
        thought.trackId = trackId
        thought.painting = awPainting.map(AWPaintingDTO::class.java)
        val mapThought = thought.map(AWThought::class.java)
        setThoughtTrackIds(mapThought, trackId)
        alreadyReadThoughts.add(mapThought)
        saveAlreadyReadThoughtsList(alreadyReadThoughts, context)
        return mapThought
    }
```

I've set the trackId and painting thought properties before the map line so the "thought" object already has the values assigned before mapping (and the new object has them once the mapping has been done), so, backwards than before.

```
thought.trackId = trackId
thought.painting = awPainting.map(AWPaintingDTO::class.java)
```

till don't understand why painting value is altered just after map, but now I don't care as it is working as expected.